# Bound DataGridView TableAdapter Update

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

An DataGridView that is bound to an DB table. I have set an tableadapter with Update command triggered by CellEndEdit event however I have some trouble calling update.

Update command:

```
UPDATE       dbo.EpsProgramacaoSubmontagem
SET                GUID = @GUID, CascoID = @CascoID, Casco = @Casco, BlocoID = @BlocoID, Bloco = @Bloco, Sub = @Sub, SSub = @SSub, Linha = @Linha, 
                         Quantidade = @Quantidade, Peso = @Peso, [Inicio Plan Montagem] = @Inicio_Plan_Montagem, Oficina = @Oficina, 
                         [Inicio Plan Submontagem] = @Inicio_Plan_Submontagem, [Termino Plan Submontagem] = @Termino_Plan_Submontagem, [Temino Real] = @Temino_Real, 
                         Turno = @Turno, [Status Processamento] = @Status_Processamento, [Status Sub] = @Status_Sub, [Data ] = @Data_
WHERE        (GUID = @Original_GUID)
```

Every TableAdapter.Update parameter from above is related to DataGridView column. I have already tried this:

```
private void SubProgDGV_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //UPDATE DE LINHA
        DataGridViewRow row = SubProgDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Guid guid = (Guid)row.Cells["gUIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
        int cascoid = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["cascoIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn3"].Value);
        string casco = row.Cells["cascoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn11"].Value.ToString();
        int blocoid = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["blocoIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn5"].Value);
        string bloco = row.Cells["blocoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn11"].Value.ToString();
        string sub = row.Cells["subDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString();
        string ssub = row.Cells["sSubDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString();
        string linha = row.Cells["linhaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        int qtd = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["quantidadeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn3"].Value);
        double peso = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["pesoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn4"].Value);
        DateTime datacmb = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["inicioPlanMontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
        string oficina = row.Cells["oficinaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        DateTime datasub = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["inicioPlanSubmontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
        DateTime datasubfim = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["terminoPlanSubmontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
        DateTime datatermino = row.Cells["teminoRealDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["teminoRealDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
        string turno = row.Cells["turnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        string statusproc = row.Cells["statusProcessamentoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        string statussub = row.Cells["statusSubDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        DateTime data = row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value);

        this.epsProgramacaoSubmontagemTableAdapter.Update(cascoid, casco, blocoid, bloco, sub, ssub, linha, qtd, peso, datacmb, oficina, datasub, datasubfim, datatermino, turno, statusproc, statussub, data , guid );
    }
```

However everytime that one of the datetimes parameters are null it throws an exception. Is there a better way to deal with this? Since I have already set the relation between DGV columns and SQL parameters shouldnt be a straightforward way?

Comment: Maybe use nullable DateTime (DateTime?)

Comment: What's the exception? Is the exception on assigning a value to your variable, or is your exception in trying to update the table?

Comment: WithMetta - DateTime is non nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no solution regarding check null or workarounds, instead I used DataGridViewDataBindSource_CurrentItemChanged event.
Every time a change occour it is triggered and automatically apply changes to DB, I think this should be autobuilded as one selects Enable Editting on a bound DataGridView.

Comment: This *solution* makes no sense. You are checking every cell on the row, regardless of `when` you check, an empty string will remain an empty string, a null will remain a null. Unless something else in your code is different, I don't see how doing the same thing on a different event fixes your problem.

Comment: I've abandonned the previous strategy and used this instead:

XBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                foreach (DataRowView item in (BindingSource)sender)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        DataRow ThisDataRow = ((DataRowView)item).Row;
                        if (ThisDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                        {
                            this.epsProgramacaoSubmontagemTableAdapter.Update(ThisDataRow);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your empty Date cell value would actually `== DBNull.Value`
What if you tried this instead?

```
DateTime data = row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value);
```

Or maybe even something like this using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` on the `.FormattedValue`

```
DateTime data = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].FormattedValue) ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value);
```

.

```
//UPDATE DE LINHA
DataGridViewRow row = SubProgDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Guid guid = (Guid)row.Cells["gUIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
int cascoid = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["cascoIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn3"].Value);
string casco = row.Cells["cascoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn11"].Value.ToString();
int blocoid = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["blocoIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn5"].Value);
string bloco = row.Cells["blocoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn11"].Value.ToString();
string sub = row.Cells["subDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString();
string ssub = row.Cells["sSubDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString();
string linha = row.Cells["linhaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
int qtd = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["quantidadeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn3"].Value);
double peso = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["pesoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn4"].Value);
DateTime datacmb = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["inicioPlanMontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
string oficina = row.Cells["oficinaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
DateTime datasub = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["inicioPlanSubmontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
DateTime datasubfim = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["terminoPlanSubmontagemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
DateTime datatermino = row.Cells["teminoRealDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["teminoRealDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
string turno = row.Cells["turnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
string statusproc = row.Cells["statusProcessamentoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
string statussub = row.Cells["statusSubDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
DateTime data = row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["dataDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way i found is to check is it null or not using IsDBNull as below code ,just remember to always use DateTime? to allow for null in all cases

```
DateTime?  PrintDate =  reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("PrintDate")) ? (DateTime?)null :  DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PrintDate")))
```

this solution had some performance prices , but it do the job

Comment: Not that it is wrong but, you are checking for DBNull against the data stored in the `reader`, he/she is trying to evaluate the content of the `DataGridViewCell`.